# Sending e-mail from sendmail with headers

Tags: email, sendmail, smtp-headers

I'm trying to send an e-mail with `sendmail`, but I need to specify some headers (From, Content-Type, Subject). Here is the command I am currently running:

`echo "Content-Type: text/plain\r\nFrom: do-not-reply@mydomain.com\r\nSubject: Test\r\n\r\nThe body goes here" | sendmail -f do-not-reply@mydomain.com admin@mydomain.com`

The problem is that the headers are not being set. Do I have the format correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `echo` with the 'e' parameter.

```
 -e  
    Enable interpretation of the following backslash-escaped characters in each STRING:  
      \n          new line  
      \r          carriage return
```

If you look at the result of sending mail with your command you see the following:

```
Content-Type: text/plain\r\nFrom: do-not-reply@mydomain.com\r\nSubject: Test\r\n\r\nThe body goes here
```

(It literally shows up as above as a single line, including the 'special characters')

Applying the above, slight, modification allows your code to work fine:

```
echo -e "Content-Type: text/plain\r\nFrom: do-not-reply@mydomain.com\r\nSubject: Test\r\n\r\nThe body goes here" | sendmail -f do-not-reply@mydomain.com admin@mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Use printf

`printf "Content-Type: text/plain\r\nFrom: do-not-reply@mydomain.com\r\nSubject: Test\r\n\r\nThe body goes here" | sendmail -f do-not-reply@mydomain.com admin@mydomain.com`

Comment: You'd be better with `printf "%s" "Content-Type...body goes here\r\n"` so that inadvertent formatting instructions in the body don't confuse.